# Can't print in Python

Tags: python, screen-scraping

I've been studying Python last few weeks to automate a work for my business.

Basically I have to do webscraping but I'm having trouble with a print function in the next-to-last code line...

```
def search_time(self):
    for item in self.items:
        print(f"Procurando {item}.")

        self.driver.get(self.bot_url)

        cpfBox = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]/div/div[1]/input')
        cpfBox.send_keys(item)

        time.sleep(2)

        cpfButton = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]/div/div[2]/button')
        cpfButton.click()

        time.sleep(2)

        self.delay = 3  # seconds



    try:
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, self.delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main"]/div[1]/h2')))
        print('CPF Valido')
    except TimeoutException:
        print('CPF Invalido')

        time.sleep(2)

        name = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/h2").text
        print(name)

        time.sleep(2)


items = ["32911769953"]


bot_url = BOT(items)
bot_url.search_time()
```

Comment: it returns me nothing if i run the code with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether the xpath is indeed the correct path to the text you want to get through selenium.

If this is a website you can go to the element that you are trying to find and right click and select Copy XPATH.

```py
try:
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, self.delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main"]/div[1]/h2')))
    name = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/h2").text
    print(name)
    time.sleep(2)
    print('CPF Valido')
except TimeoutException:
    print('CPF Invalido')
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Thanks for let me have your help Rohan!

The xpath is correct, the code works without any error but that 'print(name)' doesen't gives me nothing... It was supposed to give me the name of the client searched by his number.

I'v tried add .text but does not work to

Comment: That is quite interesting... What do you mean that it will return the name of the client searched by his number? If you use the xpath to the number it will not return the name of the client. However, the fact that its not returning anything is interesting.

Comment: Can you send more of your code in the original post?

Comment: Sory for the misunderstanding... First im giving the client number in the search box and then, on the next page, i wanna get and PRINT the client name

I'v updated the code, thanks!

Comment: Can you try moving the code that you originnally sent under the ```try:``` statement. i think that might be the issue. keep me posted.

Comment: Oh Rohan!! It seem so obviously... Thank you so mutch, really made my night, hugs from Brazil!

Answer (score 0):

First, I would recommend generalizing your xpath query.  Currently, it is heavily dependent on the entire page's structure.  A small layout change in an unrelated part of the page could give you undesirable results.  Review [xpath syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) use of `//` and predicates will save you many headaches in the future.

If that doesn't help, please post the html that you are attempting to parse.